# Trouble merging two dataframes in R (VLOOKUP)

Tags: r, web-scraping, merge

I need help merging two data frames with R. I'm a little desperate, since I have tried everthing I could. Any help would be appreciated.

The thing is that I'm doing some daily web scraping, and I need to compare today's results whith yesterday's results in order to to detect if there have been any changes.

I only have two variables (title of the page and url) in two dataframes (one for today and one for yesterday), and I want to merge them in one.

The possible changes are:

- Changes in the name.
- Changes in the url.
- New programs (new name and new url).
- Deleted programs.

I've tried with merge, cast & melt, ifelse, etc. etc. and I can't solve the problem. For example:

```
yesterday <- read.csv2("Yesterday.csv")
today <- read.csv2("Today.csv")
new <- merge(x = today, y = yesterday, all = TRUE, sort = TRUE)
```

But without the desired result. I'm attaching three files:

- [Today.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1scYdZrGYaSDr-TE8IZsy1tKSdLjMn7jt/view?usp=sharing), with the results of today scraping
- [Yesterdat.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uJ-ThiKykTjoY1gc3jlBHoab8WAJD-wP), with the results of yesterday scraping
- [Results.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lsy_2gKbp0N_CZKk3xHy7WZhH1dWDNiX/view?usp=sharing) with the desired output. A VLOOKUP in Excel, highlighting the changes I want to detect (in this case name changes).

**I would need a solution for the four changes options. The output could be different, I don't care about that, but I need the comparison to be correct** Even if you found that this question is duplicated I would need the link to the other one, because I haven't been able to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the links so you can download the data. Sorry.

Comment: Desired results are highlighted in yellow?

Comment: Yes! In yellow is marked the change. As you can see, the name has changed, but the url stays the same. Thanks.

Comment: So you didn't highlight yesterday programs, which were deleted today? Ok, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is updated in response to the comments bellow:

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(

  anti_join(today, yest) %>% 
    mutate(
      label = ifelse(programa %in% yest$programa, 'changed',     'added')
      ),
  anti_join(yest, select(today, programa)) %>%  mutate(label = "deleted")

)
```

Which, while applying it to the whole data sets, returns following results:

```
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   programa                          url                                  label
#   <chr>                             <chr>                                <chr>
# 1 Carrera de Derecho a distancia |~ https://universidadeuropea.es/onlin~ added
# 2 "Carrera de Criminolog\xeda a di~ https://universidadeuropea.es/onlin~ added
# 3 "Carrera Ingenier\xeda Inform\xe~ https://universidadeuropea.es/onlin~ added
# 4 Grado en Derecho a distancia | U~ https://universidadeuropea.es/onlin~ dele~
# 5 "Grado en Criminolog\xeda a dist~ https://universidadeuropea.es/onlin~ dele~
# 6 "Grado Ingenier\xeda Inform\xe1t~ https://universidadeuropea.es/onlin~ dele~
```

In order to check, if it is able to register changes in the programm, we can do following:

```
yest[22, 2] <- yest[23, 2]
```

Piping the changed data into the code above, returns table with additional record, labelled as `changed`:

```
# # A tibble: 7 x 3
#   programa                          url                                  label
#   <chr>                             <chr>                                <chr>
# 1 "M\xe1ster en Direcci\xf3n Hotel~ https://universidadeuropea.es/onlin~ chan~
# 2 Carrera de Derecho a distancia |~ https://universidadeuropea.es/onlin~ added
# 3 "Carrera de Criminolog\xeda a di~ https://universidadeuropea.es/onlin~ added
# 4 "Carrera Ingenier\xeda Inform\xe~ https://universidadeuropea.es/onlin~ added
# 5 Grado en Derecho a distancia | U~ https://universidadeuropea.es/onlin~ dele~
# 6 "Grado en Criminolog\xeda a dist~ https://universidadeuropea.es/onlin~ dele~
# 7 "Grado Ingenier\xeda Inform\xe1t~ https://universidadeuropea.es/onlin~ dele~
```

Explanation:

- Everything enclosed inside `bind_rows()` is combined into the single tibble. As far as we have two separate `anti_join()` statements here, and each of them returns it's own tibble, we have to `rbind` them into the one;
- `anti_join()` is a set operation, which, giving two sets A and B, returns another set C which is subset of A but not subset of B. In other words, C is the difference between A and B.

  - When we call `anti_join(today, yest)` we obtain a subset of `today` with records *either* not present in `yest` at all, or those with `program` or `url` changed comparing to `yest`. We pipe those results into `mutate()` call, and assign the value `changed` to `label`, if the value of `programa` is the same as yesterday (`programa %in% yest$programa`), while `url` value was changed. If `programa %in% yest$programa` is `FALSE`, it means that program name wasn't present in `yest` so it is a new program, and we label it as `added`.
  - When we call `anti_join()` for a second time, we are looking for the difference between `yest` and `today` program names. In other words: 'Which programs present in `yest` are not present in `today`?' We achieve this by looking for subset of `yest` with program names which are not in program names of `today` (that's why you need to `select(today, programa)`). If any of such records where detected, they are labeled by `deleted`.

*Sorry if this explanation is somewhat clumsy, but I hope it will help you to navigate the code*.

Data:

```
tmp <- tempfile()

download.file(
  "https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1scYdZrGYaSDr-TE8IZsy1tKSdLjMn7jt&export=download",
  tmp
  )

today <- read_delim(tmp, delim = ";")

download.file(
  "https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1uJ-ThiKykTjoY1gc3jlBHoab8WAJD-wP&export=download", 
  tmp
  )

yest <- read_delim(tmp, delim = ";")

file.remove(tmp)
```

Comment: Not a fan of pipes, I take it? ;-)

Comment: Not on Fridays :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer @utubun. Is what I wanted, but I don't really understand the code. I'll try to figure it out. What I would like to ask you is: what could I do if there are deleted or added programs? For example: `yest <- read_delim(tmp, delim = ";") yest <- yest[1:36,]` in case of an added program or `today<- read_delim(tmp, delim = ";") today <- today[1:36,]` in case of deleted programs? Thanks!

Comment: @Francesc I will add the explanation, give me a sec.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, you can delete "amateur R programmer" from your profile. I have learned from you today.

Comment: @KonradRudolph added more pipes :)